# Sort keyword data to show highest searches with lowest competition

Tags: seo, keyword, google-ads-api

I've used the Google Adwords tool to find suggested keywords. I want to take this data a step further:

Is there a formula or a way to sort this data to show the highest searches with the lowest competition?

I'm looking to create an additional column that will output some kind of rating, which should then show me the best keywords to target.

Just to note - I'm not actually going to be using Adwords, this is just to help me write good targeted content.

Update:
I've created an extra column and just done searches/competition and sorted it by that... on the surface it seems to give pretty good results.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a formula or a way to sort this data to show the highest searches with the lowest competition?

Warning: the competition figure returned by AdWords is the competition between advertisers, not competition between content providers (which is not available).

If you want to make money, you should multiply the search with the competition, because you want people to fight to put their ads on your page.

If you are not going to use Adwords, then your formula makes sense (assuming the competition figure is between content providers).